# Problem during parsing datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I have problem when im trying parse datetime in format like: "1.00:29:00" 1- days,29-minutes, after invoke DateTime.Parse im getting "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a valid native datetime string format - see the remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) for more info - but that sounds a lot like you're really talking about a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ParseExact providing the format to use along with the value to parse.

Comment: TryParseExact if you don't want to throw exceptions.